# Wordpress wp-admin dashboard

Tags: php, wordpress

The left dashboard does not show enough information and I'm already on domain.com/wp-admin

[image]
I'm logged in as an administrator, I was expecting more options from the left GUI. I did nothing before this and there is no error on the dev tools console. I don't have any idea where i went wrong. account is an administrator

Comment: should probably post over on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your user name can be admin but user role not the administrator, check the user role first.

Read and get the idea about wp user role,
https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities

WordPress comes with a user role management system which defines what a specific user can and cannot do on your website. Knowing these user roles and permissions are essential as your WordPress site grows. In this beginner’s guide to WordPress user roles, we will compare each WordPress user roles and permissions in an easy to follow infographic.

Out of the box when you install WordPress, there are five default user roles:

1. Administrator
2. Editor
3. Author
4. Contributor
5. Subscriber

source http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/wordpress-user-roles-and-permissions/

Comment: the account was actually an administrator. this happens after updating the wordpress website

Comment: if correctly updated nothing happened like you incident, do you have a backup?

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved

Wordpress Update made the default admin to be a normal user.

Solution : manually changed the user to be an admin from the MySQL phpmyadmin.